# unrecognized command line option “-std=c++11”

Tags: c++, c++11, raspberry-pi, wiringpi

I am trying to run wiringPi Cpp version with raspberryPi. I downloaded [this](https://github.com/SebastianNiemann/WiringPi-Cpp) and tryed to run but I go the error below.

[image]

What is the problem here? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: type g++ -v. If the version number is 4.6 or lower, game over

Comment: @user4581301: Already shown in the second and third lines of the screen capture.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade your GCC. You appear to have GCC 4.6, and the flag you mention was introduced with GCC 4.7.

Comment: Allthought I install GCC4.7, when I try to run "cmake .", I read again that "C compiler identification is GNU 4.6.3. How can I use GCC 4.7?

Comment: make sure you get the right one when you run `gcc`, and if that fails set the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables to point to your install of gcc 4.7

Answer (score 3):

Run `g++ -v` on the command line. If the version number is 4.3 through 4.6 replace `-std=c++11` with `-std=c++0x` and see if you get any love. If that still doesn't work, you'll have upgrade the compiler or remove the c++11 features from the library. Seriously recommend the former over the latter.

If the compiler is before version 4.3 definitely upgrade.

## edit

I need to read more goodly. skip getting the version number. Try `-std=c++0x`, then upgrade the compiler if it fails.